# Java enum, is it possible to cast to different types with same function?

Tags: java, enums, casting

I have a function that can receive different types of parameters somewhere in my program (boolean, int, string, date and float).
And I have an array received through an api that has this types as a string.

I had the idea of doing an enum and casting it to avoid having 5 ifs. But it seems not possible.

Right now what I have is this:

```
public enum InputType {
    text {
        @Override
        public String cast(String value) {
            return new String(value);
        }
    },
    _integer {
        @Override
        public int cast(String value) {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
    },
    NonInteger {
        @Override
        public float cast(String value) {
            return Float.parseFloat(value));
        }
    },
    _boolean {
        @Override
        public boolean cast(String value) {
            return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
        }
    },
    _date {
        @Override
        public Date cast(String value) {
            return new Date(value);
        }
    };

    public abstract String cast(String value);
    public abstract int cast(String value);
    public abstract float cast(String value);
    public abstract boolean cast(String value);
    public abstract Date cast(String value);
}
```

The idea is to be able to do in my program: someFunction(enum.cast(value)); so i can avoid doing 5 ifs and casting it.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Read about method overloading, differentiating them only by return type is forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Method signature in Java is defined by the method name and its parameters list. Your code won't compile because you have several `cast` methods with the same parameters list (including parameter type)

[Oracle Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html):

> You cannot declare more than one method with the same name and the
> same number and type of arguments, because the compiler cannot tell
> them apart.
>
> The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating methods, so you > cannot declare two methods with the same signature even if they have a different return type.

Instead, you could change your design and use interfaces with generics to solve your problem.